# composer require bower-asset/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-in-color

Tags: composer-php, bower

How to use composer to install bpmn-io/bpmn-js-in-color.

With bower the command is:

```
bower install bpmn-io/bpmn-js-in-color
```

With composer it should be:

```
composer require bower-asset/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-in-color
```

But it is not working. Any ideas?